# Move to activity designer from activity source file

Tags: android, android-studio

Is there any fast way to move from activity source file to activity designer. I'm too lazy to find `xml` file name of my activity and later go to `res->layout>activity_main.xml`

Is there any short key to switch between source and form layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just go to your onCreate function and find setContentView(R.layout.your_activity);
hold ctrl and click on your_layout to goto the design.

hope this helps
happy coding

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the setContentView() method, you should see your xml file passed as a parameter.

If you press `Cmd` + `Click` (`Control` + `Click`) on windows, you should be able to jump to the xml file directly.